# Best EPPlus NuGet version for .NET 4.x target? ..to avoid error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: .net, ssis, epplus

I'm using EPPlus in a c# script in SSIS, so have to target .NET framework 4.x
With the latest EPPlus version, 7.0.8, I get the error:

*Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.*

OS: Windows Server 2019 Data Center, .NET framework version: 4.8.03761

[Microsoft's suggested solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ASPNET-Core-web-apps-targeting-NET-50/10515999#T-N10522291) is to install SDK 7.0, but that didn't work

I've traced this dependency to *Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream (3.0.0.0, .NETCoreApp, v.6.0)*.
Noting that among the older versions of EPPLus, versions 7.0.5 and 6.2.16 use an older version of the dependency: *Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream (2.3.2.0, .NETFramework, v4.6.2)*
I'm going to use 6.2.16, because it has the higher release date of the two.

Question: Of the two versions, 6.2.16, 7.0.5, which is the more up to date in terms of features and bug fixes? 6.2.16 has a more recent release date, but is a major version behind in naming. Also, is EPPlus considering releasing a NuGet with all updates, for software targeted to .NET 4.x like mine?

Thanks!

notes:
I was able to use v7.0.8 when running SSIS from Visual Studio 2019 on my Windows 11 desktop.
Running on the server failed with the error noted above.

There are several references to the missing *System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0* problem in stack overflow that suggest retargeting the assembly reference in a config file, but I don't have that option in SSIS.

Comment: I don't understand why you think installing .NET 7 would fix a problem you are having with .NET Framework 4.x.

Comment: Just went after this myself, you'll find that they said there's an issue with the recyclable memory stream v3 with the v6/7 version of EPP. I got my stuff backed into a corner and ended up going with the deprecated 4.x branch of EPP which also addressed the licensing issue we were going to go up against.

Comment: Ian Kemp: installing SDK 7 was suggested in a Microsoft post, linked above, for the same error message, albeit in the context of Visual Studio upgrades. Based on that I'd hoped that SDK 7 would install the missing DLL.